# Format Ionic-Datetime to Firebase Timestamp

Tags: angular, firebase, datetime, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

i would like to save a user-picked datetime (using ion-datetime) in firbase as a timestamp.
Right now firebase is unfortunately saving the date as a string.

Picking date and time:

```
<ion-item>
      <ion-label>Fälligkeits Um</ion-label>
      <ion-datetime [(ngModel)]="timestamp" displayFormat="DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm" placeholder="Select Date"></ion-datetime>
    </ion-item>
```

init:

```
export class CreateToDoPage implements OnInit {

  titel = ""
  label = ""
  timestamp = ""
  constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private router: Router, public afStore: AngularFirestore) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
```

save to Firebase:

```
async createToDo() {
    const { titel, label, timestamp } = this;
    try {
      const user = await this.afAuth.currentUser;
      await this.afStore.collection("/user/" + user.uid + "/todos").add({ name: titel, label: label, due: timestamp }).then((f) => { console.log(f) }).catch((error) => { console.dir(error) });
    } catch (error) {
      console.dir(error);
    }
  }
```

I already tried to set the type of the variable timestamp:

```
timestamp: AngularFirestore.timestamp = ""
```

But than i get this error:

> [ts] 'AngularFirestore' only refers to a type, but is being used as a
> namespace here.

If you have any ideas i would be grateful :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<ion-datetime>` component outputs a string on the ngModel data, using ISO8601 format.

To pass it to firebase just transform it into a `Date` object as follows:

```js
async createToDo() {
    const { titel, label, timestamp } = this;

    try {
      const parsedDate = new Date(timestamp)
      const user = await this.afAuth.currentUser;
      await this.afStore.collection("/user/" + user.uid + "/todos").add({ name: titel, label: label, due: parsedDate }).then((f) => { console.log(f) }).catch((error) => { console.dir(error) });
    } catch (error) {
      console.dir(error);
    }
  }
```